# Animate Frame of Collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uicollectionview

I am having trouble with a rather simple concept. I have a collection view that has a frame of the view controllers view frame, whole screen, with the image view in the cell, taking up the frame of The Whole cell. Now all I want to do is when the user taps my button, it animates the collection view down to my desired frame.

> My desired frame = (0, 555, 375, 112).
>
> The current frame before pressing button is = (0, 60, 557, 375).

Here is my current code:

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if small == true {
         return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width - 100, height: collectionView.frame.height)
    }

    return CGSize(width: collectionerView.frame.width, height: collectionerView.frame.height)
}
```

And the function for animating

```
  @objc func swiperDown () {

    self.small = true 
    self.collectionerView.reloadData()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.collectionerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - 112, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 112)

        }, completion: {(_) -> Void in

    self.collectionerView.addGestureRecognizer(self.gesturSwipeUp)
        })

}
```

I keep getting the message in console

> "the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView
>   minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content
>   insets top and bottom values."

Please leave a response if you can help, I need it thanks.

Comment: You have `collectionView` and `collectionerView` in your code. Was this intended?

Comment: did you ever solve this?